# Installing nest/terminus gives dependency tree error

Tags: nestjs, npm-install

Whenever I try to install nest/terminus

```
npm i @nestjs/terminus
```

I get the following error

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
> npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! While resolving: typeorm@0.3.7
> npm ERR! Found: ioredis@4.28.5
> npm ERR! node_modules/ioredis
> npm ERR!   peer ioredis@"^4.0.0" from @nestjs-modules/ioredis@1.0.1
> npm ERR! node_modules/@nestjs-modules/ioredis
> npm ERR! @nestjs-modules/ioredis@"^1.0.1" from the root project
> npm ERR! ioredis@"^4.28.5" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
> npm ERR! peerOptional ioredis@"^5.0.4" from typeorm@0.3.7
> npm ERR! node_modules/typeorm
> npm ERR!  peertypeorm@"^0.3.0" from @nestjs/typeorm@8.1.4
> npm ERR!  node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm
> npm ERR!  @nestjs/typeorm@"^8.1.4" from the root project
> npm ERR!  typeorm@"^0.3.7" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: ioredis@5.2.1
> npm ERR! node_modules/ioredis
> npm ERR! peerOptional ioredis@"^5.0.4" from typeorm@0.3.7
> npm ERR! node_modules/typeorm
> npm ERR!     peer typeorm@"^0.3.0" from @nestjs/typeorm@8.1.4
> npm ERR!     node_modules/@nestjs/typeorm
> npm ERR!       @nestjs/typeorm@"^8.1.4" from the root project
> npm ERR!    typeorm@"^0.3.7" from the root project
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
> npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
> npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

I tried running the following command

```
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

it ran okay, but on repeating the terminus installation I got the same error. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: looks like your project is missing `typeorm@0.3.7`, that's not related with `@nestjs/terminus`. I installed it in a nestjs v9 app just fine.

Comment: that is impossible, Typeorm is not only installed but I'm also using it. I tried install terminus  with --leagcy-peer-deps and it did install but after that even npm install fails and it finds webpack missing and installing every package starts giving this error. however if I dont install terminus, everything runs fine and all other packages install correctly, if I try. Also If I remove terminus which installed with --legacy-peer-deps option, everything is back to normal. so I guess terminus is causing issues

Answer (score 0):

From the error log it looks like nestjs/terminus was missing the ioredis peer dependency. You were on ioredis@4.28.5 while terminus@0.3.7 required ioredis@5.0.4 or higher. Can resolve this by bumping the ioredis dependency.